# HTML5 cache doesn't work in Android webview

Tags: android, html, caching, android-webview, hybrid-mobile-app

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + mWebView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1024 * 1024); // 5MB
File cacheDir = getCacheDir();
if (!cacheDir.exists())
    cacheDir.mkdirs();
webSettings.setAppCachePath(cacheDir.getPath());
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
if (isNetworkAvailable())
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
else
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getApplicationContext());
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

mWebView.loadUrl("http://~~~");
```

This is my code.
And This is the error.

```
08-06 22:34:45.536 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.536 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.536 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.536 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.546 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.556 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.556 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.566 18343-18343/lk.lk W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-06 22:34:45.566 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.576 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.586 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.586 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.726 18343-18343/lk.lk D/dalvikvm: Note: class Lcom/lge/mdm/manager/ILGMDMDevicePolicyManager$Stub; has 372 unimplemented (abstract) methods
08-06 22:34:45.746 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceRequest', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity$1.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.756 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceRequest', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity$1.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.756 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.webkit.ClientCertRequest', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity$1.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.756 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceRequest', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity$1.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.756 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.webkit.PermissionRequest', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity$2.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.756 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebChromeClient$FileChooserParams', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity$2.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.756 18343-18343/lk.lk E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.webkit.PermissionRequest', referenced from method lk.lk.MainActivity$2.access$super
08-06 22:34:45.896 18343-18383/lk.lk E/chromium: [ERROR:cache_creator.cc(115)] Unable to create cache
08-06 22:34:45.896 18343-18383/lk.lk E/chromium: [ERROR:appcache_storage_impl.cc(1803)] Failed to open the appcache disk cache.
```

I don't know why my code doesn't work.
Is there a problem?

Sometimes, It works well. (Specially, after I install app (First launch))
However, When I close my app and restart my app, HTML5 cache doesn't work. And It occurs above errors.

Comment: this is related to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64620

Comment: I saw that post. But, I think that is not related to this issue.

Comment: i have no more knowledge about this but i hope this will helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392414/android-webviews-clearcache-is-very-slow and https://www.google.co.in/search?biw=1366&bih=641&q=html5+cache+is+not+loaded+second+time+in+webview+in+android&oq=html5+cache+is+not+loaded+second+time+in+webview+in+android&gs_l=serp.3...4668.33730.0.35698.23.23.0.0.0.0.174.2215.0j17.17.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..6.9.1176...30i10.2LHDTQ9_0bM

Comment: Sorry. The post you gave for me is not related to this issue. Because that is related to remove cache.