# loading large html in android webview part by part

Tags: android, webview

Since loading a large html in android webview is very slow. I would like to load it partially and as user scrolls down I load the rest.

I am using

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/css/",
                    htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

and I know I can use

```
webview.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

                }
            });
```

but I do not know how to append the rest of html as user scrolls.

**I do not want to keep loading the whole page as user scrolls**

Comment: that should be handled through html code ( not through web view ). achieving that in html will give you more freedom to display.

Comment: @AmodGokhale do you have an example for html?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no way to load html partly , because when u call

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/css/",
                htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

or

```
webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

your webView loads the entire html file, so I think u should show some animation with spinner while loading will not be completed, like here:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Hide your spinner 
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a spinner and that is not the issue. Issue is to make it load faster.

Comment: maybe this link will help you to make it faster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304237/android-webview-loading-data-performance-very-slow

Comment: If your html is very big, u can't do anything. because webview need some time for loading, and time depends to html size.

Comment: note true. AmodGokhale  suggestion was good to use html to do load more