# How to improve local file video playback performance on android TV

Tags: android, performance, webview

I created a lightweight android app that is a wrapper for an existing html/js application.  The android app only has one activity that houses the webview for the existing html/js app and some code for downloading files.   I have everything working as it should however the video playback performance is horrible on the android tv.  WEBMs run at maybe 5 fps (VP8 vs VP9 makes no difference) and MP4s run just slightly better.   There's nothing too fancy happening in the DOM. There's 2 video tags and some javascript to play and stop the videos when they are scheduled to play.   The TV runs css animations pretty smooth but the video playback performance is unacceptable.

I've tried to optimize the webview by setting the layer type to hardware if the version >= kitkat and played around the the cache settings of the webview but neither seem to help at all.

Additional info:

- The app is being tested on a hisense android tv
- The video files that are being played in the html/js app inside the webview are being saved in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/files/`
- I've tested with small (< 10MB) webms and mp4s
- I've tried everything here [Android webview loading data performance very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304237/android-webview-loading-data-performance-very-slow)  (except for the CrossWalks XWalkView)
- Android version 8
- Hisense TV Model 508HF

Is there anything else that can be done to improve the playback performance of local video files that play inside a webview or does this sound like a hardware limitation with the hisense tv?

Comment: I'm leaning toward hardware limit, but you should [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58718311/edit) your question with model and OS version of the HiSense Android TV you are testing on.

Comment: Android version and TV model added.   @MorrisonChang  Thanks.