# How to improve webview load time

Tags: android, webview

I have a URL which I can load in webview. If I open the webview through browser it takes less time, but if I load the URL in webview it takes more time. Also if I have to reuse the same webview page with the same URL in another screen then I am unable to do that because if I use the same webview object in different screens then also it takes time to load the URL.

How do I make my webview to load a URL instantly?

Comment: WebView trades speed for flexibility. If you're needing to work with web content faster, please consider using a browser intent rather than embedding a WebView in your app.  You may be able to see some improvement by disabling the liberal cacheing in WebView as seen in this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652583/enhance-webview-performance-should-be-the-same-performance-as-native-web-browser/4799448#4799448

Comment: I had done two things 1) call load methods on web views when user launches the app. 2) If the webview is not ready and user clicked the tab for it, then show a loader progress dialog

Comment: may be , this link help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow

Answer (score 1):

You could use the YSlow or Google PageLoad plugins for your browser, to get specific tips on how to improve page load and speed up your page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different cache mode: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setCacheMode%28int%29

or, if the page doesn't change, just use loadDataWithBaseURL:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

> By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not
>   enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored.

here i paste small part of code of [zirco-browser](http://code.google.com/p/zirco-browser/source/browse/trunk/src/org/zirco/ui/components/CustomWebView.java)

```
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_BROWSER_ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT, true));
            settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_BROWSER_ENABLE_IMAGES, true));
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_BROWSER_USE_WIDE_VIEWPORT, true));
            settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_BROWSER_LOAD_WITH_OVERVIEW, false));
            settings.setSaveFormData(Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_BROWSER_ENABLE_FORM_DATA, true));
            settings.setSavePassword(Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_BROWSER_ENABLE_PASSWORDS, true));
            settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.valueOf(Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getString(Constants.PREFERENCES_DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL, ZoomDensity.MEDIUM.toString())));             
            settings.setUserAgentString(Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getString(Constants.PREFERENCES_BROWSER_USER_AGENT, Constants.USER_AGENT_DEFAULT));
```

Comment: Any other optimizations you can suggest? :-)

Comment: @RavindranathAkila The question itself lac of code what user tried.. without knowing it  i would only suggested what i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

set render priority high for your web view can solve problem up to some extent
its some thing like this

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
```