# HTML5/CSS/Jquery Android app -> bad performance

Tags: android, jquery, performance, html, jquery-mobile

We made a simple Android app (game) with HTML5/CSS/Jquery and used jquery mobile. Everything latest version. There's also some javascript used.
Latest version of Phonegap (Cordova) is used to deploy it to Android via Eclipse.

We almost finished our app, everything works fine, we just need to do some final tweaking.

The problem that we are still facing is performance.
From pressing a button to showing a pop-up to screen transitions. It just doesn't feel like running naturally smooth.
I also installed an example basic jquery mobile app. Same problem, in everything you do there is a small delay and I think HTML5 and Jquery mobile are just not ready yet.

We used multiple phones so that shouldn't be the problem.

I'm not capable of programming in Java, but when installing a similar example Java app on my phone, everything ran really really smooth.

My question is, is there any alternative for our app, to make it run smooth?
Should we program in Java instead or are there other options?

- It runs smooth on a pc
- It runs better when opening the index.html file in the phone browser, but not perfect
- We tried tips from this thread: [PhoneGap - Bad Performance compared to Browser on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364868/phonegap-bad-performance-compared-to-browser-on-android)

Comment: Another reason for looking for a HTML5 alternative is browser compatibility. We noticed our app may look/behave differently on a Samsung phone than on a HTC phone...which is quiet annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you'll have to implement that game in "native" code (Java) if you want acceptable performance. I've yet to see HTML5 based applications, let alone games that provide statisfactory user experience compared to native apps. Especially on Android.

It may happen in the coming years, it keeps getting better, but we're not quite there yet IMHO.

Comment: It's not a game with 3d graphics or anything, but the CPU is made using Javascript.

The thing is, that it does need to feel native.
So I guess Java is the best way then. I saw apps made with Smali and XML files and the usual Java files.
Do you know the difference?

Answer (score 0):

If your key factor is performance then by all means develop your app as a native app. HTML5 and java script can come really handy only when you want to target multiple platforms with more concern towards the look and feel of the app while you want to maintain everything from on location.