# White page when loading while using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

We're using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 for a mobile HTML5 app at [www.tekiki.com](http://www.tekiki.com). (Check from an iPhone, or check www.tekiki.com/dandy/dandy from a desktop.)

Upon loading, JQM shows a white page between the loading screen and the first page of the app. Are there settings in JQM to repress the loading screen? The closest we found was `$.mobile.loading()`, but this only pertains to the loading text. We want the whole white screen to vanish, meaning the app should go directly from the loading screen to the first page.

Comment: firebug the page, check the last div `ui-loader` before `body` tag closing.

Comment: @Omar, are you suggesting to hide the ui-loader element with CSS? would you mind emailing us at info @at@ panabee.com? would love to see if you're interested in HTML5 consulting.

Comment: Or it could be `ui-overlay-c` class which is added to `body`, try modifying this class. Where "c" is the default page theme.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The white screen you are talking about results from this class declared in JQM CSS:

```
/*fouc*/
.ui-mobile-rendering > * { visibility: hidden; }
```

The class is added when JQM begins to initalize

```
// Add mobile, initial load "rendering" classes to docEl
$html.addClass( "ui-mobile ui-mobile-rendering" );
```

and removed on the first `pageshow`.

The whole procedure is necessary, because you would otherwise see the pre-enhanced markup until JQM is done rendering it. So if you want to "remove" it, you could declare:

```
 .ui-mobile-rendering > * { visibility: visible; }
```

but you would see all your source code being touched up by jQuery Mobile.

Workarounds I know:

**Supply pre-enhanced markup instead of JQM doing it**
This is kind of an ordeal before JQM 1.4 (where you will have much fewer generated elements and the option to tell JQM, which widgets are being provided pre-enhanced), but can be done nevertheless albeit requiring some widget rewriting.

Also from what I see in your code, your problem should be, that the iOS startup image disappears when it wants (= before JQM is initialized) vs. you having control over it and hiding it when JQM is done.

**So: Use some other means of coverup like a custom startup screen**
For example, I'm doing [this](http://www.iaasadvisor.com/) or [this](http://www.stokkers.de/members/login.cfm?app=bleed). Both applications are loaded with requireJS and use a custom startup script I wrote (after pulling my hair out with iOS startup images).

Here is how it works:

- add a class of `splash` to the body. `CSS:before` a full white background (...loading)
- add optional background image via CSS or Javascript (no jQuery or JQM, because it must run **before** either is parsed)
- remove `splash` on pageshow from the body. As you always stay on the page you loaded first (unless you use `rel="external"`, the `body` persists, so you can safely add the class to all your pages and it will only run the coverup on the first page the user loads.

This hides whatever startup screen you set when JQM is done, so you will not have a white screen. Plus it works cross-browser (vs iOS startup image) and can easily be used with different image sizes (try the 2nd application with different devices & portait/landscape).

If you want a full code sample, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think bit more info here..

- are the loading and landing pages part of the same project?
- can you make you there is no a full refresh happening between loading screen and landing page?

other suggestions:

- if both the loading and landing screen belong to same project (domain), try calling the landing page using changePage (http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/), from loading. In this manner, the loading icon should persist.
- you may point to a new landing page and see if this white screen does not show. Perhaps somethin wrong with this landing page.

Comment: thanks for this, what do you mean part of the "same separate project"? if you view www.tekiki.com/dandy/dandy from a desktop browser, you can simulate what happens on a mobile device. both the landing and loading screens belong to the same domain. if we remove JQM, the white page vanishes. that is, the white page only appeared after introducing JQM.

Comment: Hi crashlot, I just edited the sentence (remove 'separate'). If they both belong to same project so disregard what I wrote.Have you tried using 'changePage' programmatically (via javascript)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(hideSplash, 2000);
});

$(function hideSplash() {
    $.mobile.changePage("*Jquery Mobile Page here*", {
        transition: "slidedown",
        reverse: false,
        changeHash: false
    });
});
```

Add this code to any internal or external js file.