# Android browser with jQuery rendering is slow

Tags: jquery, android-browser

I have a web app that downloads about 20KB of JSON data (through jQuery/AJAX) and turns it into an HTML table with over 300 lines and 6 columns. The desktop Chrome browser handles this in under a second, but the Chrome browser on Android takes about eight seconds to render this table.

How can I find out what is taking up all the time on the browser?  Are there tools that show the Javascript code profiling like the desktop Chrome browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android webview slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's possible to perform [Remote Debugging on Android](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) to allow debugging and profiling.  This requires a USB cable and some terminal commands.