# Android WebView Hardware Acceleration Artefact Workarounds

Tags: android, css, webview, hardware-acceleration

So there's a known bug with WebView hardware acceleration in Android,
see here for example: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17352

Disabling hardware acceleration is not an option for me.

I've read these great references:

- [Android webview slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow)
- https://plus.google.com/+PaulIrish/posts/ccP98BTMd5Z
- http://riamobilesolutions.com/android-webview-scrolling-performance/

My question is that if HWA(Hardware Acceleration) is turned on, does anyone know any CSS/HTML workarounds to prevent the rendering artefacts that can occur?

I'm only seeing them when I give focus to a form field, it seems to cause vsync-esque and subpixel glitches. When I focus on the field, the whole page seems to jitter.

It seems `position: absolute` has something to do with this, too.

Did anyone get any experience solving this?

Comment: have you tried  in your webview? : 
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Answer (score 1):

add:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
backface-visibility: hidden;
perspective: 1000;
```

if you working with 3d transform.. it is a cheap trick BUT it will improve the performance espacially on iPad..

furthermore you can try to

```
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
```

AFAIK rotations can boost the performance because gpu´s are much better in rotating something..

another way is to lay down an 'without function' transformation on each element on the screen..

please let me know if i could help you.

Comment: Described actions are causing the opposite effect. Those artifacts are the result of the GPU acceleration. So leveraging the GPU is what we want to avoid. I had the same problem and unfortunately the only solution I've found so far is disabling the hardware acceleration for the whole WebView.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your class:

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH); 

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
}       
else {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with rendering when HWA was enabled. The rendering issues disappeared when I applied the following line to body (in css).

```
body {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```