# Street View : Android vs iOS

Tags: google-street-view

my current project requires the implementation of Google StreetView.

The app already exists for iOS, where everything worked pretty fine, StreetView is embedded in the view, customized with overlays and buttons and what not...it runs fast, scrolling the StreetView view is smooth, it's obviously no webview...in short, it's perfect.

Now I have to do this app for Android and I was looking all day already, but with no success. From what I found out, there is the possibility to start StreetView as a new activity, without any chance to customize it, no overlays, no buttons, just standard Google stuff. This should be pretty smooth as it is not a webview. I can't use this, as I have to customize the UI.
Now I tried the webview approach and this makes everything slower and more laggy than you'd expect from even Android... BUT...seems to be customizable. Still, as slow as it is, I can't imagine anyone having fun with it.

So, my question is, do I have any more chances to get this working (a transparent Activity on top of the StreetView Activity? - please no)? Why does Google get it right for iOS and not for Android? 
The iOS SDK just got released recently, is there a chance a new one will be coming for Android soon?

Thanks for any hints, M.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The answer lies herein : [Android webview slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow/7528833#7528833)

Turning off the hardware acceleration speeds up the rendering ... yeah, right!

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
    webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```