# Android Web View is Very slow and not responsive When compared to browser Why?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I've Tried the answers of similar questions in stack overflow but didn't work out so Please tell me whats the problem with my code and what I need to add..

In my android code I've included the following:

```
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviews);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

and then,

```
connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                connect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                uunnamed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.8:8081");


            }
        });
```

And my webclient class :

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

what is the problem why is it slow in web view and why is it fast in chrome browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android webview slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow)

Comment: @Magu I've tried the possibilities of that question, but didnt work out... Please answer the question rather than duplicating the question

Answer (score 4):

I am not a spec in apps based on web technology, but the team from the [apache cordova project](https://cordova.apache.org/) are.

Based on her code (https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/7d61a79a78c068a7a0554b0ea5699f1cf6681d56/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewEngine.java) try this settings:

```
webView.setInitialScale(0);
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
// Enable JavaScript
final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);

// Enable AppCache
// Fix for CB-2282
settings.setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1048576);
settings.setAppCachePath(databasePath);
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

They do a lot more but this could be the trick.

Full methode for init webView

```
@SuppressLint({"NewApi", "SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void initWebViewSettings() {
    webView.setInitialScale(0);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    // Enable JavaScript
    final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);

    // Set the nav dump for HTC 2.x devices (disabling for ICS, deprecated entirely for Jellybean 4.2)
    try {
        Method gingerbread_getMethod =  WebSettings.class.getMethod("setNavDump", new Class[] { boolean.class });

        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        Log.d(TAG, "CordovaWebView is running on device made by: " + manufacturer);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB &&
                android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("HTC"))
        {
            gingerbread_getMethod.invoke(settings, true);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "We are on a modern version of Android, we will deprecate HTC 2.3 devices in 2.8");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Doing the NavDump failed with bad arguments");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "This should never happen: IllegalAccessException means this isn't Android anymore");
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "This should never happen: InvocationTargetException means this isn't Android anymore.");
    }

    //We don't save any form data in the application
    settings.setSaveFormData(false);
    settings.setSavePassword(false);

    // Jellybean rightfully tried to lock this down. Too bad they didn't give us a whitelist
    // while we do this
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
    // Enable database
    // We keep this disabled because we use or shim to get around DOM_EXCEPTION_ERROR_16
    String databasePath = webView.getContext().getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);


    //Determine whether we're in debug or release mode, and turn on Debugging!
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = webView.getContext().getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
    if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0 &&
        android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        enableRemoteDebugging();
    }

    settings.setGeolocationDatabasePath(databasePath);

    // Enable DOM storage
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    // Enable built-in geolocation
    settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);

    // Enable AppCache
    // Fix for CB-2282
    settings.setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1048576);
    settings.setAppCachePath(databasePath);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    // Fix for CB-1405
    // Google issue 4641
    String defaultUserAgent = settings.getUserAgentString();

    // Fix for CB-3360
    String overrideUserAgent = preferences.getString("OverrideUserAgent", null);
    if (overrideUserAgent != null) {
        settings.setUserAgentString(overrideUserAgent);
    } else {
        String appendUserAgent = preferences.getString("AppendUserAgent", null);
        if (appendUserAgent != null) {
            settings.setUserAgentString(defaultUserAgent + " " + appendUserAgent);
        }
    }
    // End CB-3360

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);
    if (this.receiver == null) {
        this.receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                settings.getUserAgentString();
            }
        };
        webView.getContext().registerReceiver(this.receiver, intentFilter);
    }
    // end CB-1405
}
```