# Android app slow at startup time

Tags: android, performance, delay, startup

When the app starts the first time, it's slow. It takes about 5 seconds staring at a white screen before the main screen shows. After that the app works fine and quick.
I don't know why my app is slow at startup I try to clean the onCreate() and put most code in onStart() 
this my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;
private  ImageView image ;
private ProgressBar loading;
private TextView textView;
private AdView mAdView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);




    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
            .addTestDevice("00927A7823BCD302CE6574744C8B07DB")  // An example device ID
            .build();

    mAdView.loadAd(request);




    loading.setMax(100);


    //loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(isNetworkAvailable() == false){

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"no internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else {

        webView.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                textView.setText(progress + "%");
                loading.setProgress(progress);

                if (progress == 100) {

                   // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

                    //gone the progressBar
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //gone the first logo
                    image.setVisibility(View.GONE);




                    //show webview
                    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);


            }


        });


        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)

        {
            // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else

        {
            // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        //webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);







        webView.loadUrl("********");


        loading.setProgress(0);


    }


}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private class HelpClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
}
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

}

Comment: You check App is in debug or release mode ?

Comment: You're loading a web page and ads. Why do you think it  should be faster?

Comment: @MehulTank yeah i try to disable instant run but the same

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah but before i put the ads it take time to load

Comment: Hi hackout, I suggest adding some log in onStart() field and check witch code coat so much time  :)

Comment: @RustFisher How to know with log the time ?

Comment: @hackour Em... Like this: add `Log.d(TAG, "onStart: " + System.currentTimeMillis());` before and below `webView.setWebChromeClient(..)` or other code

Comment: @RustFisher ok i will different location in the code

Comment: @RustFisher 
onStart:: 1495265557410
onStart:: 1495265574030
above chromeclient:: 1495265557618
above chromeclient:: 1495265574053
below chromeclient:: 1495265557638
below chromeclient:: 1495265574088

Comment: Hi @hackour I sort the log by time and see the first network request cost too much time. So I suggest doing the network asynchronously. Try thread or AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are loading a url in webview. So it will be always slow in your mobile application.

If you want to fast execution of your app, the only way to design your own layout and handle your data through JSON.

Comment: the problem is the website not for me

Comment: mean i don't have JSON

Comment: You have already tried to possible ways to make it fast.here is a ref.,may be it helpful to you.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow