# Android webview loads too slowly

Tags: android, wordpress, nginx, woocommerce

I run Ecommerce website and have tested visitor`s page load speed using GA. (Ga has changed it to measure the speed of all users.)

But Unusually, Page loading is slow on Android devices.

Is there anything I can fix on the server side? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 + Nginx + php7 + MariaDB .

Thank you.

Comment: What's the website?

Comment: Also what are the network conditions? Are you comparing, for example, against an iOS device on the exact same WiFi network?

Answer (score 1):

Well, sure, you might want to change your website and make it as small as you can to let `Android` load it faster, but it's a common known thing:

*The Android WebView is not that fast.*

You can actually see this issue on several threads on SO, and my suggestion is to change your `WebView` code like they do here:

[Android webview slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow)

Another way of increasing performance is to let Google Chrome handle the website for you using Chrome `Custom Tabs`.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Which can be embedded in your app, without actually intenting a seperate browser app.