# Android Webview taking time to input text for large form data

Tags: android, html, listview, android-webview, android-websettings

I am doing `webview` application for Android. The application contain form which have doctor data row wise with input text needs to be enter for each doctor.
When i have less data  from the `sqlite` db from android i.e 20 to 50 rows. When i enter from mobile `keyboard` it is showing the entered value fast.
But when 80 or 150 above data fetch it is showing the enter value very slow taking too much time to show in the input text even ``keyboard is also slow when i click on input text.

I have tried below link changes
[Android webview slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow/7528833#7528833)

Below are the changes i have implemented in android code but still issue is not resolved

Set higher render priority (deprecated from API 18+):

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
    wvBusinessMonitoring.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
    // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
    wvBusinessMonitoring.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
wvBusinessMonitoring.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is not any more urgent than anyone else's.

Comment: if this issue is resolve then it is helpful for other also that why we put question on stack overflow. & In our field everything is urgent.

Comment: if anyone had rectified this bug then please share how to resolved this.