# Set LayerType for WebView in React Native

Tags: react-native, webview, hardware-acceleration

Web View causes issues with rendering until I do a touch action. So trying to disable [hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow) as
`webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`
but there is no reference for this from **react native** side.

Have took a look at all possible props from react native [web view](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview).

Should I write a customWebView and override with `nativeConfig` or is there an easier alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web View renders on priority indirectly when it is the only view returned in the component. It get lesser priority when its nested.

```
<View>
   <Webview />
<View>
```

changed the above to the following

```
<Webview />
```

and it works like a charm