# Android Webview Crushes with GL error: GL_INVALID_VALUE

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm using Webview and It crashes with the error

```
E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  GL_INVALID_VALUE
A/OpenGLRenderer: GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/BakedOpRenderer.cpp:67
--------- beginning of crash
2019-10-04 20:13:34.792 23417-23472/com.xyz A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 23472 (RenderThread)
```

Webview is configured as below with javascript enabled:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
        webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else {
        // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
        webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.setInitialScale(1);      //webview page matches the screen size.
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webview.setOnLongClickListener(v -> true);
    webview.setLongClickable(false);
}
```

The javascript is required since the HTML's assets are designed with javascript.

It is working on Android with versions 9,7,6,5 and most of the 8's. But one test device is failing with this error!

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: The suggested solution on the duplicate solved my issue.