# How can I increase Android WebView frame rate?

Tags: android-webview

I am trying to achieve a faster frame rate in a WebView.

I have an html page that contains some WebGL animation. The WebView in my Android App runs it at ~30 FPS, while the same page at ~60 FPS in Chrome, on the same device.  Is there any configuration or code that could make the webView to perform similarly to Chrome?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow) help?

Comment: Yes, I will resolve the question

Answer (score 0):

The answer from a previous, related question worked: [Android webview slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow)

After making the changes the page runs at 60 FPS in the webView.  Thank you @tomerpacific

Comment: What specifically did help? I have the exact same problem (renders smoothly in chrome but lagging in WebView), none of the solutions worked for me

Comment: Any improvement on this? I have the same problem too.