# React native WebView is slow

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I made an app using react native webview but the app is loading slow, Is there any way we can cache the webview or any other way to make it fast, I added the loader in webview when the webview loading before going to each page the loader shows for few seconds and that is not a good user experience. I tried to find a solution on the internet and also on StackOverflow but did not find any valid solution.

Comment: I have same problem here.Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I did not find any solution. If you found any solution let me know, I am still looking

Comment: Did you try and set the androidLayerType={'hardware'}, this fixed it for me.
Or did we all switch to this Thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow?rq=4