# Speed Of Html Page Load in Android Web View

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load a URL in WebView. The URL is in the format `https://<host>/<page>.html`. The minimum time taken to load is 1 second (the time difference between the Callbacks onLoadResource() and onPageFinished()). Can this be reduced further. The page has no images.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable web view cache using this

```
viewer.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT)
```

OR

```
details.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Also use can higher the priority like this

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
```

read the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) and this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128952/caching-in-android-webview), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215873/how-to-improve-webview-load-time), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow) might also help

Comment: It is still the same. None of the techniques helped in further reducing the time difference between the two callbacks. It still takes 1 second.

Comment: which device are you using?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note8, Android version 4.2.2