# how to get apache log like debugging in Android logcat

Tags: java, android

I am currently using a webview to load a webpage which contains lots of javascript and having lots of trouble debugging what exactly gets loaded and when in the webview .

Then I saw this post where the op seems to be using apache log to monitor webpage load events in his webview. 
[Enhance webView performance (should be the same performance as native Web Browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652583/enhance-webview-performance-should-be-the-same-performance-as-native-web-browse/4799448#4799448)

Can I get a similar utility plugin or anything so that I can use it with logcat in ddms view.

If possible please provide some resource as to how to configure it for android.

Comment: I think the OP is using a remote access tool (ssh?) to connect to his server and is viewing the Apache log from there. Have you tried subclassing WebView and providing your own implementations of onLoadResource, onPageFinished, and so on? That should give you some idea of if/when things are being loaded in the WebView.

Comment: well I haven't ..lemme try ..thanks for commenting

Comment: wheww it worked ... I used onloadresource method..can you please write the comment as an answer cause I want to accept is as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the OP is using a remote access tool (ssh?) to connect to his server and is viewing the Apache log from there.

You could try subclassing `WebView` and providing your own implementations of `onLoadResource`, `onPageFinished`, and so on. That should give you some idea of if/when things are being loaded in the WebView.